# How can I repeat a certain number of icons using Polymer?

Tags: html, css, svg, polymer, web-component

I just need to do something simple, but I'm baffled how to go about it.

I have a list of students with a certain number of credits. I want to display one star for every credit completed.

e.g.,

John ★
Sarah ★★
Ken ★
Jared ★★★★

The student's info is contained in JSON that is bound to each student's div, so it can be accessed via `{{student.credits}}` etc., but something like `<template repeat>` doesn't seem to be made for something like this. I also thought maybe I could just add a class such as `star2` and override the default icon CSS but since each icon uses a SVG, it doesn't want to repeat like a standard image background would.

Any helps or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *trick* I have used in [rating-element](https://github.com/dreyescat/rating-element) web component.

1. Create an array whose length will conveniently be the number of credits:

   ```
   created: function () {
     this._credits = new Array(this.credits);
   },
   ```
2. Use this convenient array in the `repeat` template:

   ```
   <template repeat="{{_ in _credits}}"></div>
     <div>★</div>
   </template>
   ```

As a reference you can take a look at the complete component in the devel branch, specifically the [template repeat](https://github.com/dreyescat/rating-element/blob/1a3cbde9e952e43dec7dd22be3daa180168f9ffc/rating-element/rating-element.html#L19-L21) and the [created callback](https://github.com/dreyescat/rating-element/blob/1a3cbde9e952e43dec7dd22be3daa180168f9ffc/rating-element/rating-element.html#L119-L128) code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Im keen on php it would be like

```
For($i=0; $i <= $score; $i++){
    echo "<img src='images/star.jpg' />";
}
```